# Print Fahrenheit-Celsius Table in Reverse

Tags: c, reverse

I have a question how to solve this objective. 
"Modify the temperature conversion program to print the table in reverse order, that is from 300 degrees t 0." THe Program is written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*print Fahrenheit-Celsius Table*/

int main()
{
    int fahr;

    for (fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr +20)
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (fahr-32)*(5.0/9.0));
}
```

Comment: Hint: instead of going from 0 to 300, you will go from 300 to 0 in your for loop.

Comment: Hint 2: use `fahr -= 20` in the increment portion of the `for()` statement.

Comment: Do I have to delete something?

Comment: I need more help , please.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for *"from 300 degrees to 0"* Now, it goes from 0 to 300 in steps of +20.

Comment: Hint 3: change `<=` to `>=`

Comment: Okay, I did it but the problem I have now is that even tho I can compile it and run it with ./a.out on my terminal it doesn't show anything

Comment: I have written: printf(fahr = 300; fahr >= 0; fahr = fahr + 20)

Answer (score 1):

The only modification that needs to be done in the `for` loop is:

```
for(fahr = 300; fahr >= 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
```

- The first part of the `for` loop initializes `fahr` to 300(upper
  limit).
- The condition `fahr >= 0` tests whether the `fahr` variable exceeds
  or meets 0 (lower limit).
- The step expression `fahr = fahr - 20` decrements the `fahr` variable
  by the step size.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the for loop initialization and termination conditions

````
/*print Fahrenheit-Celsius Table*/

int main()
{
    int fahr;

    for (fahr = 300; fahr >= 0; fahr = fahr -20)
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (fahr-32)*(5.0/9.0));
}```
````